# The code (provided by magento) against admin password-guessing to protect magento does not work for me

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, security, nginx, password

Using [this link](https://magento.com/security/best-practices/protect-your-magento-installation-password-guessing?mkt_tok=3RkMMJWWfF9wsRoivqvOZKXonjHpfsX56eguWqW2lMI%2F0ER3fOvrPUfGjI4ETcNlI%2BSLDwEYGJlv6SgFT7jAMadn3rgEXhg%3D) I made below changes to protect magento installation, but after restating the fail2ban, I could overpass the maxretry to enter wrong password and no banning happens. Considering that other configurations are working well.

Code to add to `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` :

```
[hn-nginx-retry-ban]
# Only ban after multiple retries.
# Use this for "soft" bad behaviour.
port = http,https
filter = hn-nginx-retry-ban
logpath = /var/log/nginx/access.log
bantime = 7200
maxretry = 10
```

Code to add to `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/hn-nginx-retry-ban.conf` :

```
[Definition]
# Use this for "soft" bad behaviour, as the source will only be banned after multiple retries.
failregex = ^<HOST> .+"POST \S+(/downloader/|/downloader/index.php\?A=loggedin|/admin/index/|/admin/)\s
ignoreregex =
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply run regex test to see if your filter is correct:

```
fail2ban-regex /var/log/nginx/access.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/hn-nginx-retry-ban.conf
fail2ban-regex /var/log/nginx/access.log "^<HOST> .+"POST \S+(/downloader/|/downloader/index.php\?A=loggedin|/admin/index/|/admin/)\s"
```

also make sure that your ip you run brute-force from is NOT whitelisted.